# setTimeout/setInterval timers seem to be increasing by themselves each time after firing a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have written a grease monkey script for a page which gets refreshed every 2 minutes and I have a `setTimeout` which gets triggered every 123000 (2.05). However, the timer seems to be increasing after each time it gets used.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: we can't help fix what we can't see. Post all relevant code

Comment: how about some general guidance? I know its a requirement to have code in your post however, I'm unable to replicate this in a post. Basically, I have a function which is being triggered by the setInterval and the timer seems to be out after each call

Comment: nobody is going to guess what causes unusual/unexpected behavior

Comment: _"However, the timer seems to be increasing after each time it gets used."_ How are you are observing this? Please give us _something_ to go on here. There is no guarantee that `setTimeout`/`setInterval` will fire exactly when the time elapses. That number is a _minimum_ span of time. If there are other operations going on when the time elapses, it could take longer, and over time, these difference can accumulate to cause a large difference.

Comment: Yes, I have been doing a lot of reading about the 'no guarantee' that comes with **setTimeout/setInterval**. Because of this reason, I decided to try a different way using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which allows me to fire my function at the percise time I need it.